# Is it possible to configure the location of CodeCoverage.exe in SonarQube's VSTS/AzureDevOps task

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops

I want to include the code coverage in SonarQube's scan results, but for that SonarQube needs CodeCoverage.exe to analyse the unit test results. This exe is installed through the `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer`-task. When I run the `Run Code Analysis`-task from SonarQube it says it can't find the exe. I think this is because by default it only searches for exe that is in the Visual Studio installation, but it doenst take the `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer`-task into account. (on the agent VS is NOT installed, only the SDK build tools)

Is it possible to configure the `Prepare SonarQube analysis`-task to use a different search location for the exe through the tasks Additional Properties?